# YANG model "when" statement usage

Tags: xpath, ietf-netmod-yang

I understand that the "when" statement in a Yang model takes an XPATH expression as its argument.

What is the correct YANG XPATH syntax to combine multiple expressions in order to model a type/value data container as follows ?

```
container c1 {
    leaf  attrib-type {
        type uint32;
    }
    leaf attrib-val-int {
        when "../attrib-type = 1 or ../attrib-type = 2"
        type uint32;
    }   

    leaf attrib-val-string {
        when "../attrib-type = 5 or ../attrib-type = 6"
        type string;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The XPath syntax you used is correct. The only thing you are missing are semicolons after the `when` statement.

For the complete reference to the XPath syntax used in YANG check XPath 1.0 specification.

> 6.4.  XPath Evaluations
>
> YANG relies on XML Path Language (XPath) 1.0 [[XPATH](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)] as a notation
> for specifying many inter-node references and dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

In XPath, the first condition can be written as follow :

```
when "../attrib-type[.=1 or .=2]"
```

Or if you're required to explicitly return a boolean type :

```
when "boolean(../attrib-type[.=1 or .=2])"
```

Comment: This is great for filtering `list` and `leaf-list` that are `type leafref`! Thanks